# XPath + Selector: Cannot find out a xPath to click when switching to another window

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, selector

In my flow => I have switched to another window and cannot find out the xPath to click
I have the following html => I tried some ways to click a tag [SerName] by xPath and Css Selector but they all do not work => It shows that this element cannot be find => Whether there is other way to resolve this problem. Btw, I also checked there is no iframe cover this tag

```
<div _ngcontent-blq-c9="" class="m-generalBtn m-generalBtn--sub m-generalBtn--interaction btn-past-news float-right"><a _ngcontent-blq-c9="" class="m-generalBtn__box m-generalBtn__box--sub modify-button__size -color-applied-rate m-btn__width" href="javascript:void(0)">SerName</a></div>
```

One of ways I tried but it did not work:

```
String termSegmentXpath = '//*[@id="tabUsageService"]/app-segment-details-usage-service/div/div/div[2]/div/a'
WebUI.delay(30)
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(termSegmentXpath))
JavascriptExecutor executor = ((driver) as JavascriptExecutor)
executor.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', element)
```

Comment: Can you share the URL if it's public?

Comment: I'm sorry => It's private so I cannot show it but Could you please suggest some way to me try? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are certain that there is no IFRAME which is wrapping the desired element, then try to apply selenium's `waits`. Something like below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30));
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[text()='SerName']")));
element.click();
```

Or try this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30));
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[text()='SerName']")));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

**UPDATE:** Since you edited the question and mentioned about switching to new window. Here is the code how you can go back to parent window.

First, store the current window reference as below:

```
String parentWindow= driver.getWindowHandle();
```

Then, you may have switched to new window and performed actions. Once all actions are finished, then close that window with below code:

```
driver.close();
```

Now switch back to parent window:

```
driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
```

After switching back to parent window, try to click on the desired element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below locator also using text

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()=\"SerName\"]"));
```

In the event that the "element not found" message persists, it is possible that the element is contained within an iframe or shadow DOM, making it inaccessible to Selenium without a thorough inspection of the surrounding HTML code. Without a more comprehensive analysis, it is challenging to provide an accurate assessment.

Comment: I tried the above xpath but it still didn't work => whether I need provide more what information for help? I also tried: driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); before find element but it didnt work

Comment: check if there is an iframe in html and whether this element resides inside it, share the url is possible

Comment: I checked => It only there is a the iframe below and my element is not inside it. I also checked there is no shadow-root. Sorry for it's private to share the URL. Could you please show me some ways to me try?
<noscript>
  <iframe src="https://url..." height="0" width="0"
          style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>

Comment: a notice that I have switched to another window whether it is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Set the path to the chromedriver executable
webdriver_path = 'path/to/chromedriver'

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(webdriver_path)

# Navigate to your page
driver.get('your_page_url')

try:
    # Wait for the element to be clickable
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.m-generalBtn__box.m-generalBtn__box--sub.modify-button__size.-color-applied-rate.m-btn__width')))

    # Click the element
    element.click()

    # Alternatively, you can also use XPath
    # element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='m-generalBtn__box m-generalBtn__box--sub modify-button__size -color-applied-rate m-btn__width']")))
    # element.click()

    print("Clicked the element successfully!")
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to click the element:", str(e))
finally:
    # Close the browser
    driver.quit()
```